# Proposition 1.10 ii), Chinese Remainder Theorem, A&M Introduction to Commutative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, coprime

[image]
[image]

I am working through Introduction of commutative algebra and am having trouble with the following question:
(I'll use f instead of the map,since I don't know how to input it.)

> Question 1: Why there exist a $x$ such that $f(x)=(1,0,..,0)$?

I can't find a $x$ such that $x+a_1=1$ and $x+a_i=0$ since $x+a_1=1$ implies $x=1$; $x+a_i=0$ implies $x\in \bigcap a_i$

> Question 2: Why $f(x)=(1,0,...,0)$ implies $f$ is surjective?

Comment: Q1: By assumption $\phi$ is surjective.
Q2: The product is generated by the $n$ elements $(1,0,\ldots,0)$ up to $(0,\ldots,0,1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1: By assumption $\phi$ is surjective.

Q2: The product is generated by the $n$ elements 
$$(1,0,\ldots,0), (0,1,0,\ldots,0),\ldots,\ (0,\ldots,0,1).$$

Comment: For Q1,Could you show a explain to the contradiction,since x=1 & x∈∩ai =>∩ai=(1).Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is immediate from the definition that for an ideal $I$ it holds $$1\in I\ \Rightarrow I=(1).$$